# How to fix the screen resolution in linux (lubuntu; to 1920x1080; currently stuck at 1280x1024?

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have installed the lubuntu version [18.04.4 Bionic Beaver LTS (LXDE)] and the screen resolution is for some reason fixed at 1280x1024.

I tried doing the xrandr --newmode by getting the desired screen resolution information using (cvt 1920 1080 60)

but it doesn't fix it in any way.

I get an error;
xrandr: failed to get size of gamma for outout default

Comment: Is this a bare-metal installation or a virtual machine? If the latter, the host might be passing a screen of that resolution to the guest.

Comment: its not a virtual machine